# With R: How to mark and plot a flag bit from a column in R

Tags: r, plot

Can anyone of please help with this problem.
My data frame(point_temp) or data set is like this. In this data set there are 5000+ records

```
LOCATION      TIME         ISFAILED     Temperature

Point1      8/5/2014 5:42   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:44   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:47   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:52   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 5:57   0       51
Point1      8/5/2014 6:01   1       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:02   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:07   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:12   0       44
Point1      8/5/2014 6:17   0       27
Point1      8/5/2014 6:17   0       27
Point1      8/5/2014 6:23   0       27
Point1      8/5/2014 6:28   0       27
Point2      8/1/2014 6:30   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:35   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:40   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:45   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:46   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:50   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 6:55   1       48
Point2      8/1/2014 7:00   0       48
Point2      8/1/2014 7:03   0       47
Point2      8/1/2014 7:05   0       47
Point2      8/1/2014 7:10   0       47
```

In the "IsFailed" column, wherever there is flag bit of "1" I want to mark it on the plot. Also I want to show "Point 1 and Point 2 " as two different lines on the same graph.

I mean to say is, Point 1 line will pass through all the "Times" and whenever "1" has occurred I want to highlight it so that I can note down what was the temperature & time when the Point 1 failed. Same is the case with "Point 2" also.

I want to plot "Time" on one y-axis with time interval of say (15min or 30 mins or 1 hour) and on other y-axis I want to plot the "Temperature". On the x-axis I want to show up the Date.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Please help me with this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Kindly please help me this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, one option would be to plot each time series twice: once as a line, and then a second time as set of points with their color conditional on `ISFAILED`:

```
# Use the whole data set to build the initial frame, so the entire ranges of x and y are included
with(df, plot(TIME, Temperature, type="n"))
# Now plot the first group's line and points using subset()
with(subset(df, point==1), lines(TIME, Temperature, col="black"))
with(subset(df, point==1), points(TIME, Temperature, col=ifelse(ISFAILED==1, "red", "black"), pch=20))
# Repeat for the second group
with(subset(df, point==2), lines(TIME, Temperature, col="blue"))
with(subset(df, point==2), points(TIME, Temperature, col=ifelse(ISFAILED==1, "green", "blue"), pch=20))
```

And here is the plot that produced using the play data shown at the end of this answer:
[image]

You can also do this in `ggplot`. Here is some starter code that gets the job done but could use some fine-tuning on the color selection:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=TIME, y=Temperature, group=as.factor(point), color=as.factor(point))) + geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(x=TIME, y=Temperature, group=as.factor(point), color=as.factor(ISFAILED), fill=as.factor(ISFAILED)), size=2) +
    theme(legend.position="none")
print(p)
```

Here is what that produces: 
[image]

As promised, the play data I used:

```
point1 <- data.frame(point=rep(1, 10), TIME=seq(10), Temperature=rnorm(10, 60, 15), ISFAILED=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
point2 <- data.frame(point=rep(2, 10), TIME=seq(10), Temperature=rnorm(10, 70, 10), ISFAILED=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))
df <- merge(point1, point2, all=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hello ulfelder, I am trying to understand, In your graph, can you please let me know what do the "red" points on the black line and the green points on the blue line indicate? Also whether the "Time" is in minutes or hours ? Why I am asking is because the data frame (point_temp) shows that "Point 1" is failed at "06:01 on 08/05/2014" with the "temperature 44 " and the Point 2 is failed at 06:55 on 08/01/2014 with " temperature 48" So ideally only these points should have different color on that respective line.

Comment: I want to show these two exact points on the same graph that is 
Point 1 Line - color for all "Times" with 0 will be same expect for where "1"
Point 2 Line - color for all "Times" with 0 will be same expect for where "1"
This is what my understanding is. Please let me know if I am going wrong.  Kindly please help me. 
Also can you please let me know how can I plot "Date" on the same graph , on other y-axis?

Comment: In the first plot, the red points on the black line and the green points on the blue line correspond to the times when `ISFAILED==1`. I'm not using your data, because it's a pain to try to pull the displayed table into R. I used some made-up data of my own, as shown at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: thanks for the information. It is working for me. I am using the following. First I am doing it for "Point 1" only. 

point1 <- ggplot(augfnode, aes(x=augfnode$TIME, y=augfnode$Temperature, group=as.factor(ISFAILED), color=as.factor(ISFAILED))) + geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(x=augfnode$TIME, y=augfnode$Temperature, group=as.factor(ISFAILED), color=as.factor(ISFAILED), fill=as.factor(ISFAILED)), size=4)

The problem where I am stuck is I am not able see the Time line (or time intervals) on my graph. Can you please help me in that. How can I divide the Time into intervals

Comment: I kindly request you to please help me in the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Try searching the web or Stack Overflow for other questions about axis labeling in `ggplot2`.

Comment: I tried to search on web and on Stack overflow, but I did not get the solution for that. The only thing with which I am stuck is the "time intervals" on the axis. Your code did worked for me. Only the time intervals are remaining. Please help.